# SAS Error: Undeclared array referenced: attrib

Tags: arrays, sas

Can anyone please help me with this SAS error message?

```
attrib PRODUCT_TYPE length = 8 
format = $8. 
label = 'PRODUCT_TYPE' ;

ERROR: Undeclared array referenced: attrib.

attrib ('SAS ETL') as CUSTOMER_ID length = 30 
format = $30. 
label = 'CREATD_USER_ID' ;

ERROR: Undeclared array referenced: attrib.
```

Comment: Can you post your entire code? Seems like you're mixing data step and SQL code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example should (mostly) work:

```
data _null_;
  set sashelp.class;
  attrib PRODUCT_TYPE length = $8 
        format = $8. 
        label = 'PRODUCT_TYPE' ;
    
run;
```

You need the `$` on length, but that's it.

Your second example, though, doesn't make sense - it looks more like you're writing SQL code, as it's closer to that.  You can't change the name of a variable in an [`attrib` statement](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lestmtsref/n1wxb7p9jkxycin16lz2db7idbnt.htm), and you can't refer to a variable with a space that way.

- To change a variable's name, use `rename`
- To refer to a variable that has a name with a space in it, use the syntax `'variable name'n`, a [SAS Name Literal](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lepg/p0z9rbr2w2vtd1n1q8lty9b13iv3.htm).  This is only valid if `options validvarname=any`.